# How can I design slant buttons on CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this design using HTML and CSS. I've been trying for hours, but I'm not very good at CSS:

[image]

I have tried this code here, but I want to copy the button exactly as the design above.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.button-default {
  color: white;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-slanted {
  -ms-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
}

.button-slanted-content {
  -ms-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-fixedwidth {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-default button-slanted">
  <span class="button-slanted-content">Slanted Button</span>
</div>

<div class="button-default button-slanted">
  <span class="button-slanted-content">Slanted Button with super long text</span>
</div>

<div class="button-default button-slanted button-fixedwidth">
  <span class="button-slanted-content">Slanted Button fixed width</span>
</div>
```

Also on https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/FCdsb

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Use an SVG for that and set it as background-image

Comment: I suggest to use :before and :after, but add your code please

Comment: @cloned, I want it to be dynamic, like what if the text inside the button is long the svg image will be stretched

Comment: Then split the image in two parts. You can't do this shape with pure CSS, you will need an image anyhow.

Comment: @aceraven777 I don't know why has been closed.... but why not something like https://jsfiddle.net/pc6w4fmn/

Comment: @alessandro question has been reopened now... you can continue to post your answer here

Comment: May be take a look at the [CSS Painting API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Painting_API) might not be supported very well at present but would let you do exactly what you want

Comment: Please don't use external code representation sites when a stack snippet does just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Achieve that by using `clip-path` property [play with clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

The black button is relatively easy to achieve but for white button, you have to play with `drop-shadow`

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn-black{
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 50%);
  background: black;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;  
  padding: 2rem 5rem; 
  
}

.btn-white-wrapper{;
  display: inline-block;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 0px #111) drop-shadow(2px 0px 0px #111) drop-shadow(-2px 0px 0px #111) drop-shadow(0px -2px 0px #111);
}

.btn-white{
  display: inline-block;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 50%);
  background: white;
border: 0;
  color: #111;  
  padding: 2rem 5rem;  
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>    
    <button class='btn-black'>
    CLICK ME
  </button> 
  </div>
  <div class="btn-white-wrapper">
  <button class="btn-white">
    CLICK ME
  </button>
</div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could obtain the same result using pseudo elements and hidden worflow, please find an example below

```css
    .btn-container {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      padding: 0;
      width:45px;
    }
    .my-div {
      width:25px;
      
      position: relative;
    }
    .btn {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 10px;
      outline: none;
    }
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #eee;
      
    }
    .btn:before {
      position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: -5px;
        left: -10px;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        height: 10px;
        width: 30px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="btn-container">
      <div class="my-div">
        <button class="btn">test</button>
    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of
> the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an
> element with the content property. It is inline by default.

all the best

Answer (score 1):

The basic outline and infill of the shape can be achieved by using background images which are a combination of linear-gradients.

Using CSS variables each type of button can define the colors it wants.

The two little squares can be added with before and after pseudo elements.

Here's an (almost complete) snippet to get you going. Obviously you'll want to play around with angles and so on to get exactly what you want:

```css
.button {  
  position: relative;
  width: 30vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3vmin;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
  --linew: 0.3vmin; /* the height of the border line */
  background-image: linear-gradient(-30deg, white, white 18%, var(--linecol) calc(20% - var(--linew)), black 20%, var(--bgcol) 20%, var(--bgcol) 78%, var(--linecol) 78%, var(--linecol) 80%, white 80%, white), linear-gradient(to left, var(--linecol) 0%, var(--linecol) var(--linew), var(--bgcol) var(--linew), var(--bgcol) calc(100% - var(--linew)), var(--linecol) calc(100% - var(--linew)), var(--linecol) 100%), linear-gradient(var(--linecol) 0%, var(--linecol) var(--linew), var(--bgcol) var(--linew), var(--bgcol) calc(100% - var(--linew)), var(--linecol) calc(100% - var(--linew)), var(--linecol) 100%);
}
 
.button1 {
  --linew: 0.3vmin; /* the height of the border line */
  --linecol: black;
  --bgcol: transparent;
}

div.button1.notalt::before, div.button2.notalt::before, div.button1.notalt::after, div.button1.notalt::after{
  content: '';
  width: 3vmin;
  height: 3vmin;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px black, inset 0 0 0 8px white;/*should make relative!*/
  z-index: 1;
  }
div.button1.notalt::before, div.button2.notalt::before {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

div.button1.notalt::after, div.button2.notalt::after {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.button2  {
  --linecol: black;
  --bgcol: black;
  color: white;
}

.textlink {
  --linecol: gray;
  --bgcol: gray;
}

a .textlink {
  color: orange; 
}
```

```html
<div class="button button1 notalt">Button1</div>
<div class="button button1 alt">Alt.Button1</div>
<div class="button button2 notalt">Button2</div>
<div class="button button2 alt">Alt.Button2</div>
<a href="#"><div class="button textlink">Text Link</div></div>
```